# Background image does not render within div element

Tags: angular, sass

I cannot seem to get this background image to render within my Angular component.

html

```
 <div class="bkg"></div>
```

scss

```
.bkg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../../../assets/welcome-pic.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: top center;
 }
```

I can see it in chrome dev tools. There is nothing wrong with the path, it loads fine. It just does not display in the UI.

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You are putting a background image on empty div's content, so nothing will be displayed. At least put that div inside parent div and give parent's div height and width.

Comment: Thanks this was the right way to go. I also needed to set some dimensions on the body.

Answer (score 0):

What worked, in the end, was making sure parent divs or `body` are given dimensions. Otherwise, nothing renders.

```
.bkg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url("~src/assets/welcome-pic-2.png");
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Or add dimension to `body` if no container.

```
html, body {
  margin:0px;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

This resource helped. [div height full screen](https://softauthor.com/css-make-a-div-height-full-screen/)